# How to get the timestamp of curl request before it sends?

Tags: php, security, curl

This might be impossible but...

I'd like to grab the Request Time of a CURL request just before I send it out. The goal here is to check that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` that I receive on the other end is the same as the request time I have when I send it out.

I tried just using
`<?php echo time(); ?>` when I send the CURL request, but the `time()` function returns a slightly different time locally than the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`.

Is this possible? Here is my use-case:
I would like to build a nonce that combines the current time and a salt and send it to my server. The server can grab the `REQUEST_TIME` and the salt (from the database) to check that the transaction is valid.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apart from not doable, I'd suggest you consider other options.

Comment: Look into the request headers, those might have the time from the client .... .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not doable.

Even if your servers are **perfectly** synced with their clocks to the millisecond, hardware hiccups, network latency, too many variables for it to reach at the very same second.

Do not use time for salts, generate a strong random one.

---

As for the actual question, calling `time()` will get you the time at the point of execution, right before the curl gets sent.

Comment: Okay thanks. I think I'm going to end up using SSL with username:password type security.